# Getting an `undefined` error when trying to assign values to attributes

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting an `undefined` error when trying to assign values to the properties of a custom class.

I defined a `FileArgument` class as such:

```
export class FileArgument {
  name: string;
  path: string;
  file: File;
}
```

I want to use it in my component to store information about a `file` type input field. My component looks like this:

```
export class InputModuleComponent {
    private fileArgument: FileArgument;

    onChange(event): void {
        console.log('input-module.component - onChange()');

        this.fileArgument.file = event.originalTarget.files[0];
        this.fileArgument.name = event.originalTarget.id;
        console.log(this.fileArgument);
    }
}
```

And my simplified `html` looks like:

```
<input 
    name="{{arg.name}}" 
    id="{{ arg.name }}"
    type="file"

    [(ngModel)]="moduleArguments[arg.name]"
    (change)="onChange($event)" 
>
```

When the `onChange` method is triggered, I get the following error:

```
Error: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/input/input-module/input-module.component.js class InputModuleComponent - inline template:16:9 caused by: this.fileArgument is undefined
```

If I comment out the lines where I try to assign values to `this.fileArgument.file` and `.name` my app works without errors.

EDIT: Please note the error definitely comes from assigning values to `fileArgument.file/name`. The `event.originalTarget.files/id` return values without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only assigning a type. You also need to assign an instance of the object:

```
private fileArgument: FileArgument = new FileArgument();
```